# NestedList won't render

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm building an app in Sencha Touch 2 using a PhoneGap wrapper.
I'm coding in MVC model, here is the link of the app in a webserver (for debuging): http://nqatalog.negroesquisso.pt/APP/   LOGIN: user: 1, password: 1

I have a nested list with a TreeStore to load its data, and .json file with the data.

Model

```
Ext.define('APP.model.menuitem',{
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                condig: {
                    fields: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'items']
                }
            });
```

Store

```
Ext.define('APP.store.nestedmenu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

config: {
    model: 'APP.model.menuitem',

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/menu.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
}
});
```

View

```
Ext.define('APP.view.MenuNestedList', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
xtype: 'menunestedlist',
id: 'debug',

config: {
    store: 'nestedmenu'
},
});
```

Another view, calling the previous one

```
Ext.define("APP.view.Leftmenu", {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'leftmenu',

config: {

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menunestedlist'
        }
    ],


    listeners: { 
        painted: function () {


        }
    },
},

onleafitemtap: function() {}
});
```

This nested list renders empty (as you can see and debug if you want in the link above)

Thank you for your time.

*EDIT (data/menu.json)

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Section #1",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

        "items": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Product #1",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                "leaf": true
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Product #2",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                "leaf": true
            }
        ]
    },        
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Section #2",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

        "items": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Section #3",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "name": "Product #3",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "Product #4",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Section #4",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "Product #5",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "name": "Product #6",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Section #5",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "Product #7",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Section #6",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "Product #8",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "Product #9",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "Product #10",
                        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                        "leaf": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]             
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Section #7",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",

        "items": [
            {
                "id": 18,
                "name": "Product #11",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                "leaf": true
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "name": "Product #12",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                "leaf": true
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "name": "Product #13",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
                "leaf": true
            }
        ]
    }
]       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just having this same issue and I took another look at the [NestedList sample](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/nested_list) in the Sencha documentation.  I noticed that all data and collections of data had the same keys (items/text).  I tried adjusting my JSON response and found that it worked.  Here is my code:

**JSON FROM PHP**

```
{
    "items":
    [{
            "text":"Other",
            "items":
            [{
                    "text":"Employee IDs",
                    "leaf":"true"
            }]
    }]
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
Ext.define('ListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['text']
    }
});

var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'ListItem',
    defaultRootProperty: 'items',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/get_sections.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

It looks like your Model definition has the word "condig" instead of "config".  Also, it appears as if the NestedList requires the use of "items" for collections and "text" for descriptions.

Comment: Hi. I added 'layout: fit' to my Leftmenu view. Now the list tree renders, but no text apears. Check it in my webserver.

Comment: I just changed the key: "name" to "text" and it works.  It looks like the keys have to specifically be "items" for collections and "text" for names or descriptions.  Be sure you change it in your list of fields in your Model definition.

Comment: Changed the data keys of "name" to "text" and the model as well. nothing changed

Comment: Looking at your JSON file here (http://nqatalog.negroesquisso.pt/APP/data/menu.json), the key is still called "name".

Comment: In your file "menuitem.js", you have the word "condig" instead of "config".

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time with this same problem until I realized I had forgotten to list my new Store (nestedmenu, for example) in the stores array for the application in app.js.